# On the convergence of the series $\sum \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor ne\rfloor}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, ceiling-and-floor-functions, equidistribution

The question is pretty simple:

> It the series $\sum \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor ne\rfloor}}{n}$ convergent or
>   not ?

As usual in this situation we let $S_n:=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{\lfloor ne\rfloor}$ and apply an Abel transform to the original series. Thus the convergence of the original series is equivalent to that of $\sum \frac{S_n}{n^2}$.

We have the obvious bound $S_n = O(n)$. However in order to conclude one might need to achieve a bound of the form $S_n=O(n^{\alpha})$ for some $\alpha <1$. Does anyone know a proof of this fact? (Or a proof for the original quesiton).

Comment: I don't have the time right now to work this out, but I think this rough proof sketch might work: $\mathrm e$ has [irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) $2$, so there are infinitely many integer pairs $(p,q)$ such that $\left|\mathrm e-\frac pq\right|\lt q^{-2}$. For such pairs (with $p$ and $q$ coprime), the values of $n\mathrm e\bmod2$ up to $n=2q$ are roughly equally spaced. Divide the sum into chunks of length $2q$ and use the fact that there are about as many positive as negative terms in each chunk to bound the increments.

Comment: @joriki is it possible to ellaborate on what 'roughly spaced' means ? Here you pretend that $ne=np/q+O(n/q^2)$, so how can you see that approximately half of the ne lie in $[0,1] \mod 2$?
Anyway, thank you for your comment.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2877451